# Сообщение всем клиентам Socket JAVA

Tags: java, сокет

Каким образом возможно вывести сообщение все подключённым клиентам в сокете через JAVA?

Comment: Не JAVA, а Java. А то прямо глаза режет жесть...

Answer (score 1):

Используйте список для того, чтобы хранить всех подключенных к вам пользователей.
Как отсылать и принимать сообщения можно заглянуть сюда: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/readingWriting.html - там хороший пример.